# Getting alert dialog item list to display in a different fragment, adapter or activity once clicked

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am lost on how I should implement this, I have a list of items say mango, bananas, pineapples e.t.c in general(fruits) and I am displaying them using an Alert Dialogue once you click the Select Fruit segment on my Setting Activity.

My problem now is I need to display this fruits once selected on different places, say on a class, fragment and adapter, I am just wondering how can I get the clicked item and set it on different textviews that I have in my project and are in different activities.

My simple dialog example

```
 final String[] items = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Grapes","Mango","pawpaw", "ovacado", "peach", "pears",};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("List of Items")

                .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[which] + " is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

        alertDialog.show();

        Button button = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
       button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

General idea I should be able get the selected item and display it on my adapter.

```
holder1.fruitsTextView.setText( from the alert dialog selected item "mango" + fruitsDatas.get(position).getAllFruits());
```

An image of what I am trying using this example. [That is my dialog which I want to pop up on my setting section, just an example of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9YDL.png)

[This is my Main activity text view where I want to display the selected item from the dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5dUD.png)

Comment: try using `static String[] items = {"Apple".......etc..}` it is global.

Comment: @Mysterious_android so I can access this item and it corresponds with the dialog one? still learning some Android.

Comment: @Mysterious_android say I want the clicked item to appear in this line of code holder1.fruitsTextView.setText( "mango" + fruitsDatas.get(position).getAllFruits());

Comment: Is this what you mean ? http://www.feelzdroid.com/2014/12/how-to-show-listview-in-android-alertdialog.html

Comment: Also please re-word your question it is very confusing to understand what your intentions are.

Comment: @Mysterious_android Thank you for the link, how can I get the selected items and display them on a different fragment or activity, assume it is a currency, $ and I want to display it on my expense activity and transaction activity  once someone selects a currency on the setting section. Trying to break the problem down, thank you for trying to help really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private fun showAlertWithChoiceOption() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Choose an Option")

        val picker = arrayOf("Camera", "File Explorer", "Cancel")
        builder.setItems(picker) { dialog, which ->
            when (which) {
                0 -> {
                   //Camera Choosen 
    dialog.cancel()}
                1 -> {
                    //File Explorer Choosen  
    dialog.cancel()              }
                2 -> {
//Cancel Choosen
                    dialog.cancel()
                }
            }
        }

        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        dialog.show()
    }
```

Try the above code.It is in Kotlin

Comment: I am trying to set selected items on different activities and fragments on my projects.